# Trying to Access Google Sheets and Getting Error About 'Unexpected Credentials Type'

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to run the following code to access Google Sheets.

```
import os
os.getcwd()
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pandas as pd

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret_406147946600-na19mdik9a4571623b4kdp30h5354el0.apps.googleusercontent.com.json', scope) # Your json file here
credentials
```

I got the .json file from 'OAuth 2.0 Client IDs'.  All I did was click 'DOWNLOAD JSON' and I put the file in my default folder, named 'C:\Users\ryans'.  When I run the code, I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-17-26266215508f>", line 9, in <module>
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret_406147946600-na19mdik9a4571623b4kdp30h5354el0.apps.googleusercontent.com.json', scope) # Your json file here

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\service_account.py", line 223, in from_json_keyfile_name
    revoke_uri=revoke_uri)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\service_account.py", line 172, in _from_parsed_json_keyfile
    'Expected', client.SERVICE_ACCOUNT)

ValueError: ('Unexpected credentials type', None, 'Expected', 'service_account')
```

All I'm doing is giving it the exact same file that it gave me.  That's it.  If I change the name to this: 'service_account.json', then I get the following error.

```
ValueError: ('Unexpected credentials type', None, 'Expected', 'service_account')
```

All I am doing is exactly what it is telling me to do.  I can't understand what the problem is here.  It seems like a 2-second job (copy/paste), but nothing, at all, is working here.  I've seen other example online and other people state that everything works fine, but nothing is working for me, no matter what I do.  Is there some kind of special security setting or some such thing?  Can I just disable some security, if it even exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to use Sheets API using gspread with the service account.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Issue and solution:

In your question, I could confirm as follows.

> I got the .json file from 'OAuth 2.0 Client IDs'. All I did was click 'DOWNLOAD JSON' and I put the file in my default folder, named 'C:\Users\ryans'. When I run the code, I get this error.

In this case, I thought that the downloaded file was not the credentials of the service account. That is used for OAuth2 process. I think that the client ID and client secret are included in the file. When I tested this file for your script, I could confirm that the same issue occurred.

So please create the service account and get the JSON file as follows.

- At Google Cloud Platform, you can create the service account as shown in the following image.

  [image]
- Or, also you can create the service account by accessing to https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/create.

#### Note:

> Is there some kind of special security setting or some such thing? Can I just disable some security, if it even exists?

You can also achieve this. You can also see [the official document](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#granting_access_to_a_service_account_for_a_resource).

#### References:

- [Creating and managing service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts)
- [Granting roles to a service account for specific resources](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#granting_access_to_a_service_account_for_a_resource)

If I misunderstood your situation and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.